# Atalho para comentar bloco no VS Code

Tags: javascript, css3

Bom dia pessoal, minha pergunta é mais uma curiosidade.

Por exemplo, eu sei que usando o atalho `Ctrl + ;` eu consigo comentar uma linha, exemplo: `//Comentario em linha`.
Portanto, existe algum atalho que eu possa comentar um bloco inteiro usando: `/* Exemplo de um comentario em bloco */`?

Answer (score 1):

Por padrão, é CTRL+ALT+A ou CTRL+SHIFT+A

Você pode alterar os atalhos do teclado nas configurações do VS Code:
File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts (busque por "Toggle Block Comment")